# Issue using .Net Core 2.2 LinkGenerator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In my controller.Post I am using a link generator to return the endpoint of the newly added resource  to the user. The link generator always returns null and I cant quite put my finger on why?

I included controller code that is adding to the database. Note the line calling _linkGenerator.GetPathByAction - the parameters passed in are (in order) 1. the action (in this case the name of the method that does the 'Get'), 2, the controller name and 3 an anonymous type containing the correct Id. I honestly cant see a problem with this.

how the controller name is defined :

```
namespace CarPriceComparison.Controllers.Api{

[Route("api/vehicles")]
[ApiController]
public class VehicleController : Controller
```

'Get' Action - function header :-

```
[HttpGet("{vehicleId_:int}")]
public IActionResult GetVehicle(int vehicleId_)
{
```

'problem' code that does the get. To me, the parameters passed into _linkGenerator.GetPathByAction look perfectly fine. Suggestions as to why I am always returned a null value?

```
[HttpPost("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostNewVehicleData(VehicleViewModel vehicleData_)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var newVehicle = _mapper.Map<Vehicle>(vehicleData_);
            _vehicleRepository.AddVehicle(newVehicle);
            var location = _linkGenerator.GetPathByAction("GetVehicle", "vehicles",
                                                                    new {vehicleId_ = newVehicle.Id});

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(location))
            {
                return BadRequest("could not use vehicleId_ to create a new vehicle in the dataase");
            }
            if (await _vehicleRepository.SaveChangesAsync())
            {
                var vehicleModel = _mapper.Map<VehicleViewModel>(newVehicle);

                return Created(location, _mapper.Map<VehicleViewModel>(newVehicle)); 
            }
        } 
        return BadRequest("Failed to save the vehicle");
        }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest($"Exception Thrown :  {ex}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try capital `V`, `Vehicle`. The name of the controller in this instance is `Vehicle` not vehicles, although the route is. Also, since you are inside a controller, you should use the IUrlHelper accessed as simply `Url` it is contextual in nature and does not require to specify controller/area name within the same controller/area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to try this:

```
var location = _linkGenerator.GetPathByAction("GetVehicle", "Vehicle",
                                                                    new {vehicleId_ = newVehicle.Id});
```

Or remane your controller to VehiclesController. Then try this:

```
var location = _linkGenerator.GetPathByAction("GetVehicle", "Vehicles",
                                                                    new {vehicleId_ = newVehicle.Id});
```